# ShowDialog приводит к зависанию

Tags: c#, winforms

ShowDialog формы приводит к полному зависанию приложения.

Существует кнопка по нажатию на которую вызывается специальная форма:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var RepositoriesForm = new Forms.Repositories(Forms.Repositories.How.Servers);

        RepositoriesForm.FormClosing += delegate
        {
            this.ReloadServersRepositories();
        };

        RepositoriesForm.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Конструктор:

```
public partial class Repositories : Form
{
    private How wta;

    public Repositories(How WhatToAdd)
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.wta = WhatToAdd;

        if (WhatToAdd == How.Mods)
        {
            this.Text = "Управление репозиториями модов";
        }
        else
        {
            this.Text = "Управление репозиториями серверов";
        }

        this.UpdateList();
    }
```

UpdateList():

```
private void UpdateList()
    {
        this.button2.Enabled = false;
        this.button3.Enabled = false;
        this.listBox1.Items.Clear();
        if (this.wta == How.Servers)
        {
            foreach (ArmA2ServerRepository repo in Engine.Repositories)
            {
                this.listBox1.Items.Add(repo.Name);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (ArmA2ModificationsRepository repo in Engine.ModsRepositories)
            {
                this.listBox1.Items.Add(repo.Name);
            }
        }
    }
```

Если создать Breakpoint в конструкторе форме, он будет будет вызван, форма покажется, но полностью перестанет реагировать и одна и другая. Без Breakpoint форма не покажется, но главная форма перестанет реагировать.

Почему так происходит?

**UPD1**:

При `Show()` форма появляется, но все элементы в ней белые и приложение перестает реагировать на все события, даже не скрывается.

**UPD2**:

Если не вызывать `UpdateList()` проблема всё равно сохраняется. Формы просто зависают. Такой эффект бывал от метода `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(60000);` но в данном случае он вообще нигде не вызывается

**UPD3**:

Callstack показывает что `frm.ShowDialog()` (здесь frm - форма) выполняется, но сама форма на экране не появляется, а родительское окно просто намертво зависает.

**UPD4**:

Вспомнил, возможно, важную деталь, все было предельно хорошо до удаления ссылки на ненужный Windows API Code Pack (был установлен пакетом NuGet и удален), только после этого метод `ShowDialog()` у `System.Windows.Forms.Form` перестал работать!

**UPD5**:

Пересоздал проект - результата нет.
Запустил в виртуальной машине пару раз - ничего не меняется.

Comment: Ну а что у вас в `Engine.Repositories` и `Engine.ModsRepositories`? И сделайте метод `UpdateList()` публичным и вызывайте его не в конструкторе, а извне, после конструктора. Негоже в конструкторе данные грузить.

Comment: @andreycha, Engine.Repositories и Engine.ModsRepositories это массивы, первый содержит RU24Lib.Types.ArmA2ServersRepository элементы, второй - RU24Lib.Types.ArmA2ModificationsRepository. 
Оба типа объектов массива содержат поля Name (string). В конструктор добавил следующее: `this.Load += delegate { System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => this.UpdateList()); };`. Всё равно форма не показывается, а приложение зависает.

Comment: Такой эффект обычно бывает если не прописать атрибут `[STAThread]` методу `Main(strings[] args)`. Но в моём случае он прописан.

Comment: Т.е. данные материализованы и обращение к свойству `Name` никаких побочных загрузок не дает? Не поверю. А с подпиской на `Load` и использованием `StartNew` -- это вы зря, можно огрести еще ошибок.

Comment: @andreycha, `Name` - это простое поле класса `BaseRepository`. `RU24Lib.Types.ArmA2ModificationRepository` и `RU24Lib.Types.ArmA2ServersRepository` образованы от `BaseRepository`. Тут даже особо не важно как вызывается UpdateList() он в любых случаях вызывается, даже более - проблема и не от него.

Comment: Что-то мутно у вас там. Может исходники выложите куда-то? Можно минимальный код проект, в котором воспроизводится зависание. Уверен, что проблема элементарная, но по предоставленной информации ее найти сложно.

Comment: У вас есть какие-нибудь подписки на события формы `Repositories`? `Load`, `Shown` и т.д.

Comment: @andreycha, нет, до этого времени. Сейчас снял с `Load` и повешал на `Shown` `UpdateList()`. Вот проект: 
[CloudMailRu](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/MnKS/FyBMqSTFB)

Comment: На пустых данных у меня все открывается и ничего не виснет: http://i003.radikal.ru/1506/20/2ff4417cf1dd.jpg Дайте json для `Repositories` и `ModsRepositories`. А вообще, раз чертовщина начала после установки/удаления пакета, попробуйте-ка взять исходники заново из репозитория и пересобрать начисто.

Comment: @andreycha, попробуйте добавить [этот 'репозиторий'](http://ru24.top-game.zz.mu/repo.json). Формат JSON, ветка пустая

Comment: Добавил, по-прежнему все работает.

Comment: @andreycha, проблема, судя по всему, во мне :[

Comment: @DaFriNochiterov: Попробуйте на физически другой машине, может, проблема с этим компьютером.

Answer (score 1):

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
```

Диалоги как правило завязаны на COM, поэтому должны получать в свое управление основной поток через [STAThread] чтобы обрабатывать свои WndProc сообщения или диалог должен запускаться в своем отдельном потоке или же посылать DoEvents в основном потоке.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь давать чуть более развёрнутые ответы.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin нормальный ответ.

Comment: Я думаю, что [STAThread] все-таки там есть (если его никто не убирал)

Comment: @hazzik, после правки, сделанной автором, — более чем.

Comment: `[STAThread]` присутствует в методе `Main(string[] args)` в классе, сгенерированном по умолчанию "Program.cs", именно он вызывается при запуске.

Answer (score -1):

Проблема в том, что у вас загрузка данных (UpdateList) происходит в UI-потоке. Попробуйте использовать [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker) для загрузки данных.

Comment: Аналогично. Ничего не меняется. При запуске вне Debug (из папки /bin/Debug/) появляется окно Windows "Приложение не отвечает"

Comment: @DaFriNochiterov: Подождите! То есть проблема воспроизводится только если запускать программу не из каталога Debug? Почему вы об этом не сказали? http://i.imgur.com/pBYBXGB.jpg

Comment: @VladD, она воспроизводится везде. И при отладке и при обычном запуске, и при запуске из-под администратора, и из-под запуска на виртуалке. Только разница между отладкой и обычным запуском: при обычном запуске всплывает окно "Приложение не отвечает." и предлагает 'поискать решения проблемы'

Comment: @DaFriNochiterov: Окей, ну что, начнём расследование? Для начала, если пройти под отладчиком, какая строка зависает? `var RepositoriesForm = new Forms.Repositories(Forms.Repositories.How.Servers);` или `RepositoriesForm.ShowDialog();`?

Comment: @VladD, В UPD3 написал: 
> Callstack показывает что frm.ShowDialog() (здесь frm - форма) выполняется, но сама форма на экране не появляется, а родительское окно просто намертво зависает.

Comment: @DaFriNochiterov: Ага, хорошо. Значит, функция `UpdateList()` не при чём. А приведите-ка _весь_ call stack, может, будет видно что-то подозрительное.

Comment: @VladD, только если `[External Code]`, особо ничего нет.

Comment: @DaFriNochiterov: Хорошо, а что есть на форме? Попробуйте выкидывать контролы до тех пор, пока не перестанет зависать. (При этом, понятно, придётся выкидывать и кое-какие куски кода.) Найдите тот контрол, который «виноват».

Comment: @VladD, Кстати, с `MessageBox` почти то же самое, только он, бывает, показывается, но при нажатии на кнопку "ОК" закрывается, а форма всё также остается заблокирована, callstack ссылается на `Show()`

Comment: @DaFriNochiterov: А если убрать `RepositoriesForm.FormClosing += delegate {...`? И что происходит, если с формы убрать _вообще все_ контролы?

Comment: @VladD, убрано. Ничего не изменилось, метод не вызывается. Убраны - ничего не изменилось. При `Show()`, однако, хоть обе формы зависают, но на месте контролов был белый цвет. То же самое было, когда в ивент `Load` прописывают `Thread.Sleep(5000)`. Только тут он не прописан никак.

Comment: @DaFriNochiterov: Попробуйте унести скомпилированный проект на другую машину и запустить там.

Comment: @VladD, в VirtualBox создал машину с чистого образа Windows 8.1 (у меня 7). Установил, попробовал запустить программу, работает до момента, пока не нажму на некоторые кнопки (те которое показывают другие формы) происходит зависание намертво "(Не отвечает)".